# Best way to get all required inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have form, where exist few required fields **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ss9sbbcy/2/)**

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="mpassword">Password<span class="required">                                       * </span></label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="password" id="mpassword" name="mpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password"/> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="memail">Email <span class="required">* </span></label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="email" id="memail" name="memail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"/> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="mname">Full name<span class="required">* </span></label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" id="mname" name="mname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" value="MyName"/> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
       <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="mname">Nick name</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" id="mname" name="mname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter nickname"/> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Problem, i don't know what is correct way to get all required fields as they don't have `required` attribute or class. Only labels have `required` class, which means "*this input is required*"

Comment: Just get them and then what? $("label. required").closest(".form-group").find("input") will get all the required (in your case) inputs.

Comment: @LShetty, em.. yes... you are right:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just target the labels, and then get the inputs based on the `for` attribute

```
$('label:has(.required)').map(function() {
    return $('#' + $(this).attr('for'));
});
```

Note that two of the form elements have the same name ?

Comment: same names - yes, it's only in example

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - I'm not sure I got it, I see your use of filter to check the values, but if that was the OP's intention, and it probably is, using `form.checkValidity()` is probably the right answer ?

Comment: I don't know. If he wants a function for that, he can use it inside. If he already haves the element collection and don't want to re-select them, he can pass through a parameter.. I'm no sure whats the OP's intention at all. I think that the `map()`+ `filter()` solution more clean and efficient than any other jquery each or simple for loop, actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.required').next().find('input').each(function() {
  // handle elements
});
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, It would be helpful to explain why it would work or the specific conditions required to make this solution work.